# Embedded C: Add values in a list throw the las one out

Tags: c, embedded

I want collect 250 float values and when the collector is full I will throw the last Element and add the new one to the top. I cant use malloc in my stm32 Microcontroller.

how can I solve this problem in C?

Answer (score 3):

You use an array of 250 floats and simply run it as a circular buffer.

The following pseudo-code shows how to do this:

```
def array as float[250]
def count = 0
def position = 0
while x = getNextValue:
    if count < 250:
        count++
    array[position] = x
    position = (position + 1) % 250
```

What this code does is to simply write each value to a position in the array. Before the array is full (`count < 250`), you can use `count` to work out which values are populated (indexes 0 through `count - 1` inclusive).

Once it fills up, the `position = (position + 1) % 250` will roll back around to zero, effectively setting it up so that the next write erases the current earliest value.

Comment: +1. For a bit of background: [Wikipedia entry "Circular buffer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It's a very useful data structure that every developer needs to know, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Just implement a simple FIFO queue, using a cyclic buffer (an array and an index to the current position):

```
#define SIZE 250

float array[SIZE] = {0};
unsigned int index = 0;

float insert(float newVal)
{
    float oldVal = array[index];
    array[index] = newVal;
    index = (index+1)%SIZE;
    return oldVal; // In case you wanna do something with it...
}
```

If you define `SIZE` as 256 (or any other power of 2 for that matter), then it will improve the runtime performance of the index-incrementing operation, by avoiding the division involved in `% SIZE`:

```
#define SIZE 256

float array[SIZE] = {0};
unsigned int index = 0;

float insert(float newVal)
{
    float oldVal = array[index&(SIZE-1)];
    array[index&(SIZE-1)] = newVal;
    index++;
    return oldVal; // In case you wanna do something with it...
}
```

Note that if you have multiple threads inserting values, then you need to protect `array` and `index` with some OS resource such as Mutex or Semaphore.

Comment: Why `(index+SIZE)%SIZE`? Also, incrementing the index boundless has the disadvantage that you'll get a wrong "jump" to zero when `index` overflows and `SIZE` is not a multiple of 2. Instead, only do `array[index]` and then `index++; index %= SIZE;` to increment and roll over.

Comment: Correct; No point in `(index+SIZE)%SIZE`, as it can simply be `index%SIZE`. However, both allow you to increment `index` bounlessly, and they are equivalent to your suggestion above.

Comment: Still has the overflow bug: imagine `unsigned int` would be a 16-bit value. Now `65535 % 250 == 35`, but if you increase the value it will overflow and you get `0 % 250 == 0`. Ooops, your index jumped from 35 to 0 instead of 36 :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're absolutely right, I stand corrected. Guess I'm just used to "2-power" buffer size, which make the index incrementing a little more efficient. Will revise my answer; thank you.

Comment: Its not working you need remove index++ and if I add two new values only the second will add to the new place (your second solution).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to say. As I mentioned in the answer above, if you have multiple threads inserting values, then you need to protect array and index with some OS resource such as Mutex or Semaphore.